# How to import patch files in to android project

Tags: android, import, settings, patch

I want to build the http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/wiki/SmartcardAPI this smart card api project.can anyone tell me how to import patch files(the reason i want to import jar but in (https://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/downloads/detail?name=smartcard-api-3_0_0.tgz&can=1&q=) here have the patch files how can i get the jar files???)

regards
ssv

Answer (score 0):

Just run these commands,
$ cd 
$ patch -p1 < /smartcard-api.patch
$ patch -p1 < /uicc-OEM_SPECIFIC.patch
$ patch -p1 < /cts.patch

After that you can create the required jars.
The changes are there in the existing source files, so no point getting jar files.